# How to aggregate contiguous rows in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an immense amount of user data (billions of rows) where I need to summarize the amount of time spent in a specific state by each user.

Let's say it's historical web data, and I want to sum the amount of time each user has spent on the site.  The data only says if the user is present.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 1), ("A", 2), ("A",  3),("B", 4 ),("B", 5 ),("A", 6 ),("A", 7 ),("A", 8 )], ["user","timestamp"])

+----+---------+
|user|timestamp|
+----+---------+
|   A|        1|
|   A|        2|
|   A|        3|
|   B|        4|
|   B|        5|
|   A|        6|
|   A|        7|
|   A|        8|
+----+---------+
```

The correct answer would be this since I'm summing the total per contiguous segment.

```
+----+---------+
|user|   ttl   |
+----+---------+
|   A|        4|
|   B|        1|
+----+---------+
```

I tried doing a max()-min() and groupby but that resulted in segment A being 8-1 and gave the wrong answer.

In sqlite I was able to get the answer by creating a partition number and then finding the difference and summing.  I created the partition with this...

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE a.user <>
  ( SELECT b.user
    FROM foobar AS b
    WHERE a.timestamp > b.timestamp
    ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ))  
    OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) c,
user,
timestamp
FROM foobar a;
```

which gave me...

```
+----+---------+---+
|user|timestamp| c |  
+----+---------+---+
|   A|        1| 1 |
|   A|        2| 1 |
|   A|        3| 1 |
|   B|        4| 2 |
|   B|        5| 2 |
|   A|        6| 3 |
|   A|        7| 3 |
|   A|        8| 3 |
+----+---------+---+
```

Then the LAST() - FIRST() functions in sql made that easy to finish.

Any ideas on how to scale this and do it in pyspark?  I can't seem to find adequate substitutes for the "count(*) where(...)" sqlite offered

Comment: It feels like you should be able to use a Window function here..

Answer (score 1):

We can do this:

1. Create the DataFrame

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import max, min
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 1), ("A", 2), ("A",  3),("B", 4 ),("B", 5 ),("A", 6 ),("A", 7 ),("A", 8 )], ["user","timestamp"])
df.show()

+----+---------+
|user|timestamp|
+----+---------+
|   A|        1|
|   A|        2|
|   A|        3|
|   B|        4|
|   B|        5|
|   A|        6|
|   A|        7|
|   A|        8|
+----+---------+
```

2. Assign a `row_number` to each row, which are ordered by `timestamp`. The column `dummy` is used such that we can use `window` function `row_number`.

```
df = df.withColumn('dummy', F.lit(1))
w1 = Window.partitionBy('dummy').orderBy('timestamp')
df = df.withColumn('row_number', F.row_number().over(w1))
df.show()

+----+---------+-----+----------+
|user|timestamp|dummy|row_number|
+----+---------+-----+----------+
|   A|        1|    1|         1|
|   A|        2|    1|         2|
|   A|        3|    1|         3|
|   B|        4|    1|         4|
|   B|        5|    1|         5|
|   A|        6|    1|         6|
|   A|        7|    1|         7|
|   A|        8|    1|         8|
+----+---------+-----+----------+
```

3. We want to create a sub group within each user group here.

(1) For each `user` group, compute the difference of current row's `row_number` to previous row's `row_number`. So any difference larger than 1 indicating there's a new contiguous group. This results `diff`, note the first row in each group has a value of `-1`.

(2) We then assign `null` to every row with `diff==1`. This results column `diff2`.

(3) Next, we use the `last` function to fill the rows with `diff2 == null` using the last non-null value in column `diff2`. This results `subgroupid`.

This is the sub group we want to create for each user group.

```
w2 = Window.partitionBy('user').orderBy('timestamp')
df = df.withColumn('diff', df['row_number'] - F.lag('row_number').over(w2)).fillna(-1)
df = df.withColumn('diff2', F.when(df['diff']==1, None).otherwise(F.abs(df['diff'])))
df = df.withColumn('subgroupid', F.last(F.col('diff2'), True).over(w2))
df.show()

+----+---------+-----+----------+----+-----+----------+
|user|timestamp|dummy|row_number|diff|diff2|subgroupid|
+----+---------+-----+----------+----+-----+----------+
|   B|        4|    1|         4|  -1|    1|         1|
|   B|        5|    1|         5|   1| null|         1|
|   A|        1|    1|         1|  -1|    1|         1|
|   A|        2|    1|         2|   1| null|         1|
|   A|        3|    1|         3|   1| null|         1|
|   A|        6|    1|         6|   3|    3|         3|
|   A|        7|    1|         7|   1| null|         3|
|   A|        8|    1|         8|   1| null|         3|
+----+---------+-----+----------+----+-----+----------+
```

4. We now group by both `user` and `subgroupid` to compute the time each user spent on each contiguous time interval.

Lastly, we group by `user` only to sum up the total time spent by each user.

```
s = "(max('timestamp') - min('timestamp'))"
df = df.groupBy(['user', 'subgroupid']).agg(eval(s))
s = s.replace("'","")
df = df.groupBy('user').sum(s).select('user', F.col("sum(" + s + ")").alias('total_time'))
df.show()

+----+----------+
|user|total_time|
+----+----------+
|   B|         1|
|   A|         4|
+----+----------+
```